# Creating a raster object from a gridded data set in R

Tags: r, object, raster

I have a dataset with dimensions 360x180x720 (lon x lat x time). I would like to change its resolution from 1 deg to 0.25 deg using the disaggregate function that's part of R's raster package. I haven't been able to figure out how to create a raster object from this dataset. I think I need to do something involving stacking the data corresponding to each time step in layers, but I what I've tried so far has been unsuccessful. I apologize if this is a trivial question, but most of the online guidance I've seen has been directed towards data formatted spreadsheet style in (lat, lon) pairs (rather than a gridded dataset).

I appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: So you want to do 720 separate 2d interpolations of 360 x 180 data while respecting the continuity at the extremes of longitude? There's nothing fundamentally difficult about converting a matrix to a melted dataframe. The as.data.frame.table function has been around for quite some time. I suggest you post a small dataset, say 15 x 10 x 3.

Comment: Have you looked at the raster `resample` function?